# Automatically Transition Epic to In Progress when a linked story move to in progress

Tags: groovy, jira

I am currently on JIRA 7.3 and I have scriptRunner installed and I am not familiar with groovy, I also have no idea where to start, and what each of the JIRA managers means, where to find a list of these managers and their descriptions.

I would like to have a functionality where the Epic will automatically transition to "In Progress" when one of the linked issues move. Also when all stories move to "To Do" or "Done" the Epic will automatically transition to the same status as the linked issues.

Any links to tutorials, videos or a script with explanations will help.  Your assistance is highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find an example below that shows how to find an issue's linked epic and to update the epic's state by performing a transition. This is a Groovy script for ScriptRunner. I quick-tested this in the script console but you could use such a script with a post function of a workflow transition.

```
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.CustomFieldManager;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.fields.CustomField;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.Issue;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.MutableIssue;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.IssueManager;

import com.atlassian.jira.issue.IssueInputParameters;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.IssueInputParametersImpl;
import com.atlassian.jira.bc.issue.IssueService

CustomFieldManager customFieldManager = ComponentAccessor.getCustomFieldManager();
IssueManager issueManager = ComponentAccessor.getIssueManager();
IssueService issueService = ComponentAccessor.getComponent(IssueService);
CustomField epicLinkField = customFieldManager.getCustomFieldObjectByName('Epic Link');

//hardcode lookup to issue for script console:
MutableIssue issue = issueManager.getIssueObject("FID-15"); 

IssueInputParameters issueInputParameters = new IssueInputParametersImpl([:]);

//lookup the corresponding epic via the subtask's parent
MutableIssue epic = issueManager.getIssueObject(
    (String)issue.getCustomFieldValue(epicLinkField)
);

// 21 is the transition ID in my workflow
IssueService.TransitionValidationResult validationResult = 
    issueService.validateTransition(epic.getAssignee(), 
    epic.id, 21 as Integer, issueInputParameters)

def errorCollection = validationResult.errorCollection
log.error(errorCollection)
if (! errorCollection.hasAnyErrors()) {
    issueService.transition(epic.getAssignee(), validationResult)
    log.error("OK")
}
else {
    log.error("ERROR")
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. One question thought. Is there a way I can do it without hard coding the issue look up ?

Comment: Yes, of course. With ScriptRunner you could either create a post function to a workflow transition or a (event) listener. The SR docs explain [how to deal with these issue events](https://scriptrunner.adaptavist.com/5.0.0/jira/listeners.html#_custom_listeners)